# Terraform replaces aws_api_gateway_deployment in each deployment, despite triggers seem constant?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Terraform replaces `aws_api_gateway_deployment` in each deployment, despite triggers seem constant.

Here, `local.rendered_openapi` is the result of `templatefile(var.template_path, local.openapi_vars)`, which is constant (`local.openapi_vars` never change).

So, the issue seems to be caused by `jsonencode({ for k, v in data.aws_default_tags.default_tags: k => v if k != "DeploymentId" }`. Here `DeploymentId` changes on every deploy, but it's filtered out.

May `jsonencode` on a dictionary result in a different JSON encoding, since Terraform provides no guarantees with regards to ordering of keys/values?

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_gateway" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(join(",", [jsonencode(local.rendered_openapi), jsonencode({ for k, v in data.aws_default_tags.default_tags: k => v if k != "DeploymentId" } )]))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code for me to attempt reproducing your problem

Comment: If I was to troubleshoot this I will output the `data.aws_default_tags` see what/why it change, it should not change if nothing is changing

Comment: Have you tried this without the `sha1` call, so that the `redeployment` string will show the JSON-encoded values directly? That might give a clue as to exactly what's changing, whereas the `sha1` checksum is hiding the underlying value.

Comment: (I don't mean to say that removing `sha1` should solve the problem, but that it might make it easier to diagnose _what the problem is_. You can re-add it again once the problem is solved.)